# Go: Deserialize array string

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, go, slice

I have a string as: - `["a","b","c"]`. How to parse / convert it into a Go array? I can do string parsing but is there any out of the box function in Go for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)?

```
s := `["a","b","c"]`

var arr []string
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &arr); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%q", arr)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zOXSW9UQmu)):

```
["a" "b" "c"]
```

But know that package [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) does a lot of reflection kung-fu under the hood, it's faster if you write the parsing yourself. On the other hand, package `json` will also handle random white-spaces in the input – even newline characters and Unicode sequences, like this one (it's equivalent to `["a","b","c"]`):

```
s := `[ "a" , "b"  
 ,"\u0063"  ]  `
```

Comment: Ah, I thought that string has to be {["a","b","c"]} for unmarshal to work, but again an array is json object by itself